# Simple Javascript: How to invoke a function based off user prompt;

Tags: javascript

I've defined some functions, and I want to get user input to invoke those functions. I have the following code, but can't figure out how to invoke the actual function when I'm using a variable. I assumed below code would work..

thanks!

```
var someFunctions = {
  play: function() {
    if (player.stopped()) {
      player.play();
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }


var getCommand = function(){

  var command = prompt("Please enter a command");

  if (!(command in someFunctions)) {
    alert('command not recognized');
    getCommand();
  } else {
    command();
  }

}

getCommand();
```

Comment: `command` is a string - only the property name. You can't call it. You'll have to access the method: `someFunctions[command]()`

Answer (score 1):

```
var someFunctions = {
  play: function() {
     if (player.stopped()) {
        player.play();
     } 
     else {
        return false;
     }
  }
};

var getCommand = function(){
   var commandInput = prompt("Please enter a command");
   var command = someFunctions[commandInput];

   if (!command) {
      alert('command not recognized');
      getCommand();
   } 
   else {
      command();
   }
};

getCommand();
```

Comment: They're not. They're placed on `someFunctions`!

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code isn't working is because you're missing the closing `}` of `someFunctions`.

```
var someFunctions = {
  play: function() {
    if (player.stopped()) {
      player.play();
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
} // here
```

Your call is fine, you call a "variable" function the same way you do a regular one. The only difference between a "variable" function and an ordinary one is you can call the ordinary one before it's declared (if you're in the same scope at least)